# Does setting DataKeyNames property make sense when dynamically binding data?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am new to asp.net and want to know that does setting DataKeyNames property make sense when dynamically binding data? I have bind data using following code

```
gvCategory.DataSource = objCategoryInfo;
gvCategory.DataBind();
```

here gvCategory is my gridview that I created at designview and objCategoryInfo is my datasource. Is it necessay to set DataKeyNames property at design time.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessay to set DataKeyNames property at design time.?

Only if you want the automatic update or delete feature to work with GridView

[GridView.DataKeyNames Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)

> Use the DataKeyNames property to specify the field or fields that
>   represent the primary key of the data source. **You must set the
>   DataKeyNames property in order for the automatic update and delete
>   features** of the GridView control to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you only need to set DataKeyNames if you want to be able to use the GridView to update or delete data in the database. So it makes sense to set it if you need to use your GridView to do this.